# Ошибка ImportError: No module named sklearn.feature_extraction.text

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

Делаю простенькую нейросеть
Вот код:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pickle
import re
from Stemmer import Stemmer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


def text_cleaner(text):
    text = text.lower()
    stemmer = Stemmer('russian')
    text = ' '.join( stemmer.stemWords( text.split() ) ) 
    text = re.sub( r'\b\d+\b', ' digit ', text )
    return  text 




def load_data():   
    data = { 'text':[],'tag':[] }
    for line in open('1.txt'):
        if(not('#' in line)):
            row = line.split("@") 
            data['text'] += [row[0]]
            data['tag'] += [row[1]]
    return data


def train_test_split( data, validation_split = 0.1):
    sz = len(data['text'])
    indices = np.arange(sz)
    np.random.shuffle(indices)

    X = [ data['text'][i] for i in indices ]
    Y = [ data['tag'][i] for i in indices ]
    nb_validation_samples = int( validation_split * sz )

    return { 
        'train': { 'x': X[:-nb_validation_samples], 'y': Y[:-nb_validation_samples]  },
        'test': { 'x': X[-nb_validation_samples:], 'y': Y[-nb_validation_samples:]  }
    }


# - - - -

def openai():
    data = load_data()
    D = train_test_split( data )
    text_clf = Pipeline([
                    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
                    ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge')),
                    ])
    text_clf.fit(D['train']['x'], D['train']['y'])
    predicted = text_clf.predict( D['train']['x'] )



    z=input("Enter answer: ")
    zz=[]
    zz.append(z)
    predicted = text_clf.predict(zz) 
    print(predicted[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(openai())
```

При запуске выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 6, in <module>
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
ImportError: No module named sklearn.feature_extraction.text
```

Система:linux kubuntu

Comment: В чем ошибка написано в тексте ошибки. Исправить - установив указанный модуль.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка `No module named sklearn.feature_extraction.text` переводится как "Нет модуля `sklearn.feature_extraction.text`". Обычно такая ошибка означает, что модуль не установлен или не установлена библиотека, в которую этот модуль входит.

Устанавливаем библиотеку sklearn целиком (будем считать, что pip3 у вас уже установлен):

```
pip3 install sklearn
```

Пробуем импортировать:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
```

ошибок нет.

Answer (score 0):

В логе ошибки указано что это из-за 6-й строки кода, а именно о том что не найден или не может быть экспортирован модуль "sklearn.feature_extraction.text". Если это внешняя библиотека то попробуйте проверить наличие данного модуля и/или правильность написания имени файла.

P.S. Может даже из-за формата этого же модуля ругаться

Comment: У меня линукс, как поставить туда эту библиотеку ? Устанавливал через терминал

Comment: @K0T0V, `pip3 install sklearn`

Comment: @K0T0V Фраза "у меня Linux" -- это ниочём, хорошо бы указать что у вас конкретно стоит: debian\ubunty\centos\archlinux\etc и версию.

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже возникали ошибки, установил все нужные модули. И все равно ошибка. Поменял формат файла с примерами для обучения с рекоммендованного UTF-8 на ANSI и всё заработало.